# (Dis)proving an equality related to sets of even numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Working on a problem, I have reached the following identity:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{n+1-i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-2)(x_{n+1-i}-2)=2(x_{i}x_{n+1-i}-x_{i}-x_{n+1-i})$$

Where $x_1<x_2<...<x_n$ are distinct positive even numbers, and $n=4k$, $k\in\mathbb N$. I have not been able neither to find any set of even numbers satisfying the identity, nor to prove that it can not hold for any given set. Any hint / help would be welcomed.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Some things I do not know how to make use of them:

- As the RHS value is fixed for a given set $x_1<x_2<...<x_n$, the equality can hold only if $x_{i}x_{n+1-i}-x_{i}-x_{n+1-i}$ has the same value for every pair of values $x_{i}, x_{n+1-i}$.
- $\gcd (x_{i},x_{i}-2)=2$ for every $x_i$.
- A subtle transformation might lead to some more insight. Adding $2$ to both sides of the equality, yields $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{n+1-i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-2)(x_{n+1-i}-2)+2=2((x_{i}-1)(x_{n+1-i}-1))$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-2)(x_{n+1-i}-2)+2((x_{i}-1)(x_{n+1-i}-1))-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{n+1-i}=2$$

**EDIT 2**

This edit addresses the petition to give more context.

The equality is very much related to the existence of odd perfect numbers, so my question is probably very hard to solve. It can be derived noting that if we have some odd perfect number $P$ with proper divisors other than $1$ and $P$ being $x_1-1<x_2-1<...<x_n-1$, then we have that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{n+1-i}= Pn+(P-1)+n$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-2)(x_{n+1-i}-2)=Pn-(P-1)+n$$ and thus, that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{n+1-i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-2)(x_{n+1-i}-2)=2(P-1)=2(x_{i}x_{n+1-i}-x_{i}-x_{n+1-i})$$ Therefore, I believe that finding arguments for this equality not to hold (or the contrary) may lead to a better comprehension of the problem.

**EDIT 3**

I have been asked for details about the proof that any odd perfect number must have $m=4k+2$ divisors. It follows:

Let $P=p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}...p_{r}^{a_{r}}$ be some perfect number expressed in prime factorization.

Applying that the number of divisors of any positive integer $n=p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}...p_{r}^{a_{r}}$ is equal to $\left(a_{1}+1\right)\left(a_{2}+1\right)...\left(a_{r}+1\right)$ we have that $m=\left(\left(a_{1}+1\right)\left(a_{2}+1\right)...\left(a_{n}+1\right)\right)$.

From Euler's Odd perfect number theorem, we have that all $a_{i}$ are even, excepting one of them, which is of the form $4k+1$. It follows that the expression $\left(\left(a_{1}+1\right)\left(a_{2}+1\right)...\left(4k+2\right)\right)$ is of the form $4k+2$, and thus we have that an odd perfect number $P$ must have $m=4k+2$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, divisors.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying out the product in the subtracted sum and simplifying?

Comment: For a particular ordered list of distinct even integers, the expression on the left of the = sign is a sum of products minus a different sum of products. Hence once the sums are computed no subscript $i$ will appear in the result. However the expression on the right of the = sign is not summed over, and thus can have various values depending on $i$. Did you mean for there to be a summation symbol on the right side of the = sign?

Comment: Juan-- Two things: First, it would be good if you include an explanation of how your proposed identity came about, such as you were trying to show something and got the formula somehow. [then someone could check whether your identity is the right one for  the situation] Second, just to be clear, are you asking whether there exists at least one value of $k$ and corresponding ordered set of $4k$ distinct even numbers such that your proposed identity holds? [because it is easy to find cases where it does not hold]

Comment: Details would help. Suggestion: state clearly the problem involving proper divisors, as well as the steps taken that lead to your proposed identity.

Comment: Important question!! are the even numbers $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ all positive?

Comment: @coffeemath important detail to add to the OP, edited acordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148472/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-juan-moreno).

Comment: You give a list of $n$ divisors of $P$ other than $1,P$ and elsewhere say $n=4k.$ This implies the total number of divisors of $P$ must be of form $4k+2.$ Is that obvious, that is, is it inconceivable that an odd perfect number have its total number of divisors be a multiple of $4$?

Comment: 1) your formula is for number of all divisors, proper or not. 2) I'd need more explanation why an odd perfect number has 8k proper divisors.

Comment: That |R|=|S| is clear as a perfect number is not a square. Note that nothing about the parity |R| or |S| follows from the *members* of the sets R,S being odd. I fail to see how to conclude |R| and |S| are both even. Of course they are equal so |R|+|S| is even. But none of your manipulations convince me the size of set R itself is even. There might be 5 terms in R and 5 in S.

Comment: @coffeemath now you can find the correct proof that the total number of divisors of $P$ must be of the form $4k+2$

Comment: Yes, I can see 4k+2 follows from Euler's result. [I couldn't follow your approach very well without the use of Euler...]